# How to determine whether a two-variable function is injective, surjective or bijective?

Tags: functions

```
1.f(x,y) = x^2 +1
2.f(x,y) = x + y +2
from Z x Z to Z
```

I have never learned how to determine the type of two-variable functions before, and they're quite confusing for me.
At first, I intended to pick tow random values to prove that the first function is not injective, but it has a second variable y, and I am not sure if same technique would work. Please explain to me, thank you

Answer (score 2):

The general way to prove injectivity or surjectivity is as follows (this is specialized to your case where $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and all variables are real):

- To prove a function is injective: Assume that $f(x_1,y_1)=f(x_2,y_2)$ and prove that $x_1=x_2$ and $y_1=y_2$.
- To prove that a function is not injective: Find an example of $(x_1,y_1)\not=(x_2,y_2)$ where $f(x_1,y_1)=f(x_2,y_2)$.
- To prove a function is surjective: Pick any $z$ and construct a *formula* for $x$ and $y$ so that $f(x,y)=z$.
- To prove a function is not surjective: Find an example of a $z$ and show that it is impossible for $f(x,y)=z$ for any $(x,y)$.